# How to display message using label with fade in/fade out in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Does anyone know how to make a code that will display text in label using fade in/fade out.

Example: I had a form and a label`(VISIBLE = FALSE)` inside it.

If I click a button(Let's say `Button1`).

The label will become visible and it will start to fade in .

Maybe it is only for 2 seconds. And after the 2 seconds the label will become `VISIBLE = FALSE`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A label has a background. Do you want the label to fade in/out or the text only?

Comment: the label dont had a background. Maybe the Label if it can be faded in/out.

Answer (score 1):

A reliable way to make a visual effect in Winforms is by using custom drawing, ideally with DirectDraw. There you have full control over the drawing process. If you use Timer workaround for this, you will notice an irregular/annoying flicker. WPF was a good suggestion, if you are after animating your form. See, WinForms are not built for animation, this technology is supposed to be light on system resources and run on very old and outdated hardware, over RDP with a very slow network connection.

I know what you are thinking... "How can you stand the static/boring grey-on-grey stuff?". Well, it turns out that users are actually okay with this limitation, because what matters is how your software solves their problems, not how nice it is. At least this is true for many business applications. For example, major famous store chains are still using 30-year old DOS-like prompts, where not even the animation, the mouse isn't there. I also know at least one insurance company in Canada, where part of the functionality is in text-only interface, and everybody's okay with that.

If you are not developing a business application, WinForms is not a good choice as a platform.

Answer (score 0):

This was found [here](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/862666-vbnet-label-opacity/)  where the user was looking to make a label translucent. I'm sure you'll be able to get some benefit from looking into this!

```
Imports System
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms

' <summary>
' A label that can be transparent.
' </summary>
Public Class TransparentLabel
    Inherits Control
    ' <summary>
    ' Creates a new "TransparentLabel" instance.
    ' </summary>
    Public Sub New()
        TabStop = False
        Dim transparencyValue As Integer = 15 '0 is all transparent, 255 is solid
        ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(transparencyValue, ForeColor.R, ForeColor.G, ForeColor.B)
    End Sub

    ' <summary>
    ' Gets the creation parameters.
    ' </summary>
    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
        Get
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H20
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property

    ' <summary>
    ' Paints the background.
    ' </summary>
    ' <param name="e">E.</param>
    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
        ' do nothing
    End Sub

    ' <summary>
    ' Paints the control.
    ' </summary>
    ' <param name="e">E.</param>
    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
        Using brush As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(ForeColor)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, brush, -1, 0)
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

---

**EDIT**

After a short bit of research, [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20054/A-Transparent-Translucent-Label-Control-with-Movin) appeared from the code project. It sets the image to translucent.

With this, combines with a `timer` should allow you to generate what you're looking for.

So, within the time_Tick event, have your 'fading code'. After the opacity has reached 0, simply stop the timer and reset. :)

**edit for the edit**

[this link](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?586798-RESOLVED-label-fade-out) is a discussion board which discusses how to do it (hopefully).

Comment: If you could use WPF, it would be much easier, as there are more controls and it's easier to 'do the stuff you want' - but winforms is a lot more 'learnable', and hence it's a great starting point for new programmers. If you could, have a look into WPF and things *will* get easer for 'complex' ideas.